# how many lines does that word appear at inside of a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find the lines the word "Alice" appear at inside of the alice.txt file that I created. I'm also using a word dictionary to keep count of the number of times the word "Alice" appears inside of text file, and the line numbers the word "Alice" appears on inside of the text file, and the chapter number "Alice" is located at inside of my text file. Right now I'm trying figure out how many lines the word appears at inside of my text file. I stripped the word, and I split the words already, but I don't know what to do after this. I tried typing if for word in line increment the line number by 1 but it just prints the 1st and 2nd lines.

Here's my code:

```
import re

file = open('alice.txt', 'r')

word_dictionary = {
 'rabbit' : {'count' : 51, 
            'lines' : [ 1, 2, 3, 9, 26, 31, 63, 65, 66, 70, 72, 73, 74, 79, 80, 81, 192, 200, 201],
           'chapters' : ['I','IV',] 
           },
'Alice' : {'count' : 52,
           'lines' : [ 5, 8, 17, 23, 29, 49, 57, 83, 93, 96, 104, 109, 117, 123, 126, 133, 137, 149, 161, 169, 175, 183, 190, 197, 204, 224, 232, 240, 249, 253, 264, 270, 306, 314, 327, 338, 346, 357, 368, 370, 374, 381, 384, 388, 397, 399, 405, 413, 419, 435, 438, 445],
           'chapters' : ['I', 'II']


    }
}


  text = file.readlines()
  chapter_number = ''
  line_number = 0

  word = input("Enter the word to search for: ")

  #reads each line
  for line in text:
      line = line.strip()
      line = line.split()
      if word in line: 
        line_number += 1
        print(line_number)

 def count_of_words():
     print('The word count for ',word, 'is', word_dictionary[word]['count'])

 def count_of_lines():
     print('The lines that this word occurs is', word_dictionary[word]['lines'])

 def count_of_chapters():
     print('The chapters that this word occurs in is', word_dictionary[word] 
     ['lines'])
```

Comment: Line number should increment no matter the word is in the line or not.

Comment: Your word dictionary already has data, shouldn't you start from a dictionary without values, and update the dictionary when you find the word? Also, please close the file when you have read the data.

Comment: @Stefan Your right, I was just showing how the data structure is going to look like that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (I use a string instead of a file).

```
 entry={'count' : 0,
       'lines' : [ ],
       'chapters' : []}
 word_dictionary = {}

 #file = open('alice.txt', 'r')
 #text = file.readlines()
 text='Rabbit, hole, Alice, \nAlice '.split('\n')
 chapter_number = ''
 line_number = 0

 word = 'Alice'
 word_dictionary[word]=entry
 print(word_dictionary)
 #reads each line
 for line in text:
    line = line.strip()
    words= line.split()
    for text_word in words:
        if text_word==word:
           word_dictionary[word]['count']+=1
    line_number += 1
    print(line_number)

 print(word_dictionary)
```

Edit: searches for whole words, but does not handle words ending in punctuation, nor upper case vs. lower case.

Comment: I'm trying to look through a .txt file for all the lines that match the word the user typed in. So if the user typed in "Alice" as the word that they were looking for then the output of the program would be the line numbers that tell you where the word is located at and the chapter number, and how many times the word appeared when it is iterating over the .txt file.

Comment: I get that - I think my suggestion could get you started - modify the code as needed